# proxy settings for snap store

Tags: networking, proxy

This has been really frustrating, and pretty  much unsolvable for me.

I am on an university network, so naturally I use proxy. I have set proxy appropriately in /etc/environment. But, always, no matter what I do,  there's always this error:

```
   https://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/refresh: proxyconnect tcp: tls:
   oversized record received with length 20527
```

I have restarted, reset, removed and installed snap, but time and again, there's no solution. The past solutions are no help, and anything I do doesn't change the errors. Is snap store really unusable in a proxy?

Edit: I changed a few things, and now I get a differnt error:

```
   https://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/refresh: Proxy Authentication Required
```

This is really infuriating because wherever I use proxy, I use the format

username:password@host:port

whether it is /etc/environment, ~/.bashrc or /etc/apt/apt.conf. I have no problem in connectivity via apt, and wget works fine too. It's snap that snaps me.

Answer (score 0):

To use a proxy server with snapd, I replaced the following line in /etc/systemd/system/snapd.service.d/https-proxy.conf.

```
Environment="https_proxy=https://192.168.14.14:3128/"
```

I replaced `https://` with `http://`.

```
Environment="https_proxy=http://192.168.14.14:3128/"
```

I got the idea reading [Got error "tls: oversized record received with length 20527" when using https_proxy for oc exec](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/15839#issuecomment-411569148).

Comment: How do I do this for proxy with username/password authentication?

Comment: @2one do it like this: http://USERNAME:PASSWORD@SERVER:PORT