# Installing/finding snap package over proxy

Tags: software-installation, proxy, snap

When I try to search for available snap packages over proxy connection:

```
snap find atom
```

I get the following error:

```
error: Get
       https://api.snapcraft.io/api/v1/snaps/search?confinement=strict%2Cclassic&fields=anon_download_url%2Carchitecture%2Cchannel%2Cdownload_sha3_384%2Csummary%2Cdescription%2Cbinary_filesize%2Cdownload_url%2Clast_updated%2Cpackage_name%2Cprices%2Cpublisher%2Cratings_average%2Crevision%2Csnap_id%2Clicense%2Cbase%2Cmedia%2Csupport_url%2Ccontact%2Ctitle%2Ccontent%2Cversion%2Corigin%2Cdeveloper_id%2Cdeveloper_name%2Cdeveloper_validation%2Cprivate%2Cconfinement%2Ccommon_ids&q=atom&scope=wide:
       proxyconnect tcp: tls: oversized record received with length 20527
```

My question is not a duplicate of [proxy settings for snap store](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1124566/proxy-settings-for-snap-store)

because my config for https proxy is already:

```
https_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:3128/
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found the source of the problem.
There is also a file for environment variables:

```
/etc/environment
```

where `https_proxy` had `=https://`

Changing it to `http://` and then restarting

```
sudo systemctl restart snapd.service
```

fixed the problem.